# Golang Prometheus Metrics API to expose metrics in Prometheus

Tags: go, prometheus, metrics, rest

I am trying to create a REST API using Golang to provide metrics to Prometheus. I already have REST API available that is available on for example: `http://localhost:37631/prometheusJobs`
The API works fine after testing on swagger, I get the response content as followed, for now it's just the sample of text format I got from Prometheus documentation.

[image: swagger]

In my Golang function, I define as followed:

```
func GetPrometheusJobsHandler(params jobs_management.GetPrometheusJobsParams) middleware.Responder {
    ret := ""

    // TODO : construct metrics
    ret += `
# HELP http_requests_total The total number of HTTP requests.
# TYPE http_requests_total counter
http_requests_total{method="post",code="200"} 1027 1395066363000
http_requests_total{method="post",code="400"}    3 1395066363000
    `

    return jobs_management.NewGetPrometheusJobsOK().WithPayload(ret)
}
```

Then, I ran my main.go to run the API.
Then, in my `prometheus.yml`, I configured as followed to scrape on this target which is correct as I see the config in Prometheus:

```
- job_name: 'prometheusJobs'
    metrics_path: '/prometheusJobs'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:37631']
```

I see this configuration in Prometheus:

[image: prometheus]

The `/prometheusJobs` is the correct `metrics_path` as its the name of the API.

[image: API]

But on Prometheus, I don't see my text at all, the text that I specified in the Golang function:

```
# HELP http_requests_total The total number of HTTP requests.
# TYPE http_requests_total counter
http_requests_total{method="post",code="200"} 1027 1395066363000
http_requests_total{method="post",code="400"}    3 1395066363000
```

Also when I check the `up` metrics on Prometheus, the value for `prometheusJobs` is `0`

[image: prometheus2]

Could you please let me know what I did wrong in the Golang function?

[image: prometheusTargetStatus]

Comment: When you click in Prometheus on "Status -> Targets" do you see `prometheusJobs` there and is it `up`? (Also, a tip: please use `/metrics` that's the convention  ;)

Further: do not expose the metrics manually but follow the steps in https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/go-application/

Comment: @Michael Hausenblas ah yes, thank you very much, I didn't know we can check status like this [PrometheusTargetStatus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVQQE.png) I see there is an error. I will need to change the metrics path to `/metrics` then. I think I saw this doc before but not sure if it's matched with what we are trying to do, as we are trying to re-use the API we already have to connect ArangoDB to Prometheus (for statistics data of the data in the DB).

Comment: Roger that. You got a connection refused there. Try to `curl` that endpoint to see if that very address resolves and you get something back on the command line.

Comment: @Michael Hausenblas thank you, I realized its the localhost issue as I ran Prometheus using docker-compose so it doesn't recognize localhost or even when I changed to IP address, it's still localhost. Therefore I raised another question here, if you know the solution, I would be so grateful if you can please take a look:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67585625/how-to-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-machine-from-docker-container-using-docke
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello @Michael Hausenblas I have finally revolved this issue with the target down. Now my target is up, however, now I cannot see these output in Prometheus:
# HELP http_requests_total The total number of HTTP requests.
# TYPE http_requests_total counter
http_requests_total{method="post",code="200"} 1027 1395066363000
http_requests_total{method="post",code="400"}    3 1395066363000
Is it because I need to use the libraries in this link (https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/go-application/) , for ex "client_golang/prometheus/promauto" instead of printing out in string?

Comment: You totally should use the library, yes.

Comment: Ok @Michael Hausenblas thank you very much. I am checking the library.